# how to specify a null key when using util:map

Tags: java, spring

When I have such a construct in a spring beans xml file using util:map, how do I specify null for one of the keys. Here's what I'm trying to do

```
<property name="fileExtensionMap">
   <util:map>
      <entry key="pdf"  value="application/pdf" />
      <entry key="xml"  value="text/xml" />
      <entry key=<null>  value="text/plain" />   <!-- default to text/plain if key is null -->
   </util:map>
</property>
```

Comment: I find your design rather odd. You should use a real default value instead of `null`.

Comment: Usage would be something to the effect of :
String type = fileExtensionMap.get(extension); 

In the event the 'extension' variable is null, type would be simply default to the value of 'text/plain' as per the above snippet.

Comment: Well, you can change your design to write a wrapper method for the `get` that will use the default value instead of searching for `null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can specify null using attributes, but have to use separate XML elements for key and value:

```
<util:map>
   <entry>
      <key><null/></key>
      <value>...</value>
   </entry>
</util:map>
```

Comment: It's worth noting that if the value needs to be a Spring expression (SpEL), the value can be declared as an attribute and they null key can be declared as a child element

Answer (score 1):

you have to use the  markup to include null values.

Example:

```
<entry>
  <key><null/></key>
  <value>"text/plain"</value>
</entry>
```

As null is a special type, use te null element. In properties also you can use like this

```
<property name="nullProperty"><null/><property/>
```